# Open Application In C

Tags: c, windows

Is there a way I can open an application from a simple command in C?

This is my current code:

```
int main()
{
    char input;

    printf("Hello! How may I help you? \n");
    scanf("%s", input);

    if(input == "Open Google Chrome" || "open google chrome" || "open chrome" || "run google chrome" || "run chrome" || "Run Google Chrome" || "Run Chrome" || "Open Chrome"){
        printf("Sure! Opening Google Chrome...");
        system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
        printf("Done!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But all it does is tell me that my program has stopped working and quits...

Comment: What makes you think this `input == "Open Google Chrome" || "open google chrome" || "open chrome" || "run google chrome" || "run chrome" || "Run Google Chrome" || "Run Chrome" || "Open Chrome"` is going to compare the strings with `input`?

Comment: Not compare; but see which one it is. I'm used to php and I've noticed php is a lot like C, so I assume it will work

Comment: You need to learn a real programming language, [tag:php] is not a real programming language, and it certainly is not like [tag:c], don't offend [tag:c] that way. If the code you posted works in [tag:php], then you just gave me a new reason to hate it.

Comment: `\ ` should be `\\` in launch command string

Comment: scanf("%s", input);
                   ^ here, & is missing, hence your program is crashing.

change `char input` to `char input[100];`

Comment: @iharob I normally use it for web developing. god dayum

Comment: @mksteve what? they're exactly the same...

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Please don't confuse languages with similar syntax. Just because two languages *look* similar, doesn't mean they are the same language. You have to scrap what you know about php when you write in C (similarly, don't assume things that work in C will work in php).

Comment: @PCLuddite just trying new things...

Comment: *"I'm used to php and I've noticed php is a lot like C, so I assume it will work"*, no offence (really), but that's priceless :D. PHP syntax is superficially similar to C. The languages are otherwise nothing alike. Do not assume *anything* about C based on your PHP knowledge.

Comment: \ should be \\ formatting got me

Comment: [Please don't add "thanks" to your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/260312).

Comment: @vaultah I'm being polite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reason your program crash is this -

```
char input;              // char variable can hold single character
printf("Hello! How may I help you? \n");
scanf("%s", input);             // %s expects char * you pass a char
```

Declare `input` as an array -

```
char input[100];
...
fgets(input,100,stdin);    // don't use scanf as before suggested  
char *position;
if ((position = strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL)     
  *position= '\0';                             // to remove trailing '\n'
```

And this - `system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");` should be written as -

```
system("Start C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
```

This -

```
if(input == "Open Google Chrome" || "open google chrome" || "open chrome" || "run google
```

is not going to work . Use [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) to compare strings -

```
if (strcmp(input,"Open Google Chrome") == 0)    // similarly compare other strings.
```

Comment: @iharob  It wasn't a problem Sir . Always welcome for suggestions and to make improvements :)

Comment: @iharob Alright, so I was just running it, everything worked fine, but then when i said "open chrome", it came up with `The system cannot find C:Program`? What is going on here?

Comment: You must escape the ``\`` character like this ``\\``. Please enable compilation warnings, I don't know what compiler you are using but they all have warnings and diagnostics.

Comment: @iharob I'm using GNU

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic  Then compile with warnings enables with flags `-Wall -Wextra` .

Comment: I recommend working in a Linux OS then. And you enable warnings for gcc with `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` and so on, `-Wall` has all the basic warnings, then `-Wextra` and `-Wshadow` add two important ones. There is also `-pedantic` which is really pedantic. If you want the compiler to emit an error when a warning is issued, then `-Werror`.

Comment: @iharob `Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'`? Why isn't it going to Program Files (x86)?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Try `system("Start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"");`

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Maybe `system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"");`? I don't have a windows system to test currently....

Comment: @CoolGuy  Took care of that . Still your way was clean .

Answer (score 8):

Your code has several problems:

1. You have `char input;` which can store a *single* `char`. But you want to store a string. So, change that into an array of some size:

   ```
   char input[64];
   ```
2. You have `scanf("%s", input);`. `%s` stops on encountering a whitespace character. In order to read spaces upto a newline character(`'\n'`), use the `%[` format specifier:

   ```
   scanf("%63[^\n]%*c", input); /* %*c is not required; It discards the \n character */
                                /* %[^\n] scans everything until a '\n' */
                                /* The 63 prevents Buffer overflows */
                                /* It is better to check scanf's return value to see if it was successful */
   ```
3. You have `if(input == "Open Google Chrome" || "open google chrome" || "open chrome" || "run google chrome" || "run chrome" || "Run Google Chrome" || "Run Chrome" || "Open Chrome"){`. This doesn't do what you expect. It compares whether the address of the first element of `input` has the same address of that of the string literals. Also, chaining OR operators like that doesn't do what you expect.

   You'll need to include `string.h` and use `strcmp`:

   ```
   if(strcmp(input, "Open Google Chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "open google chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "open chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "run google chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "run chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "Run Google Chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "Run Chrome") == 0 || strcmp(input, "Open Chrome") == 0){
   ```
4. Also, as other people have pointed out, you need to escape the `\` character in the `system` function by using `\\` instead of `\`. You might need to enclose the whole thing in double quotes(`"..."`) too.

Comment: thankyou so much! this is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. A char is supposed to contain only one character like 's' or 't' or '5'. "open google chrome" is a chain of characters. If you want to compar the string input with "open google chrome" for example you need to create an array like that: char[10] input; for example, it will create a array that can contain 10 characters. Then to compar each character you need to do something like:
char *str = "open google chrome"
and then compar each charater by character:
if (input[0] == str[0])

But you already have some function in the library that does that for you (strcmp I think). And you can't do:
 if (intput[0] == 'r' || 't' || 'v')
you need to do:
 if (intput[0] == 'r' || input[0] == 't' || input[0] == 'v')

This is a global idea maybe there are some mistakes, it's been a while I didn't touch C lol.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code, others have pointed them out already so I won't. I, however, want to post how I would go about doing what you want.

Here it is...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (void)
{
    char input[100];

    char *chrome_answers[] = {
        "Open Google Chrome",
        "open google chrome",
        "open chrome",
        "run google chrome",
        "run chrome",
        "Run Google Chrome",
        "Run Chrome",
        "Open Chrome"
    };

    int chrome_length = sizeof (chrome_answers) / sizeof (*chrome_answers);
    int i;

    printf ("Hello! How may I help you? \n");
    scanf ("%99[^\n]s", input);

    for (i = 0; i < chrome_length; i++) {
        if (strcmp (input, chrome_answers[i]) == 0) {
            printf ("Sure! Opening Google Chrome... ");
            fflush (stdout);
            system ("Start C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
            printf ("Done!\n");

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The main thing is I would use an array of possible valid "answers", instead of a long "if statement" like you have in your code, which just gets even longer when you use `strcmp` as needed.