# How to open any application through c/c++ program with cross platform approach other than qt?

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, cross-platform

Hi i want to open any application that has been installed on the system through terminal or c/c++ program.

The reason i said through terminal or c/c++ is the command which we use in terminal will also be used in c/c++ program!!.

I referred this link [Open Application In C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806889/open-application-in-c) but its not a cross platform one. I came to know that **system** command is used with **open** to launch any application from mac.For Example:- **open -a "Google chrome"** through terminal and if wanted in c/c++ program it will be **system("open -a 'Google chrome'");** .

But how to open any installed application in linux? Or Windows? and how to make it cross platform c/c++?? i know based on macros we can identify **OS** and execute respective commands based on **OS**. But i want to know to open application in linux and windows?

Sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(){
    system("open -a 'Google chrome'");
    return 0;
}
```

This code works in Mac, But based on my research i found in linux it has to be the path of the application that is enough. Please can anyone clarify this? **I need a cross platform solution!!**

Comment: Did you try it out on linux?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX yes i tried it doesnt work in that way!! for example in linux , if i use /usr/bin/google-chrome it works but not for every application. So i need clear way to include it in a c/c++ program.

Comment: `system` is the only standard solution that exists. Of couse the details of how it works are highly platform specific.

Comment: @Karthikgr and what would you do if google-chrome is not installed in `/usr/bin/google-chrome` and you have another path? Do you know about the `PATH` environment variable? http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: @RoQuOTriX what i thought was i would use "which google-chrome" will give you the path and that i would use!!. But what i need is in general i want to launch any application from the c/c++ program.

Comment: @john after researching i got to know about system but wanted to make my c/c++ program a cross platform one, but i was not able to launch all the applications in linux as i was using in mac where i have mentioned that though my sample program.

Comment: @Karthikgr If system doesn't launch applications on your linux box, then it's because you don't have your linux box set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's insane that this question is over a year old and the only answer implies pumping several megabytes into a program that otherwise wouldn't need it.

You can use platform-specific preprocessor directives to achieve what you want.

```
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
static int platform = 1;
#elif _WIN64
static int platform= 1;
#elif __linux__
static int platform = 2;
#elif __APPLE__
static int platform = 3;
#else
static int platform = 0;
#endif


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string str;
  std::string p = "https://crouton.net";
  if(platform) switch(platform)
    {
    case 1:
      str = "explorer";
      break;
    case 2:
      str = "xdg-open";
      break;
    case 3:
      str = "open";
      break;
    default:
      return 1; // Should never happen on the 3 defined platforms
    }
  str.append(" " + p);
  std::system(str.data());
  return 0;
}
```

It is important to keep in mind that this code can be run on more than just Windows, Mac and Linux. The usage of `__APPLE__` is based on the assumption that what you're developing is a desktop program -- it likely wouldn't work on iOS, where the definition is still valid.

This example will only work for URLs (e.g. you can't replace the URL with the name of an application). If you don't know the path of what you're trying to open, you can attempt to get it using other platform-specific commands, but it's never guaranteed that you will find it even if the user has it installed. It is a very platform-specific thing because Windows applications often don't utilize the PATH, as they're expected far less to be invoked on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qt cross-platform C++ framework](https://wiki.qt.io/About_Qt), and  with regard to specifically starting the process, use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details) to start a program, or [QDesktopServices](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#details):

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <QProcess>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // You can specify the path in some config file
    const QString pathToApp = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable";

    // Open an application by given path
    // No need to add "open" or some other OS-specific prefix
    QProcess::startDetached(pathToApp);

    // OR
    // Open target web address in a default system browser in any OS
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("www.google.com"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution for this? It has to be c++, may be i can use some library but not Qt.